# Colors rearranges x-axis in 'likert' - how do I avoid this?

Tags: r, plot, likert

When i use the 'likert' package for plots, adding custom colors rearranges the options (x-axis). How do i avoid this?

I can illustrate it with the example data:

```
library(likert)
library(tidyverse)
data(pisaitems)
items29 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) == 'ST25Q']
names(items29) <- c("Magazines", "Comic books", "Fiction", 
                    "Non-fiction books", "Newspapers")
l29 <- likert(items29)
plot(l29)
```

In this example, the categories are in order ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlNW6.png))

But when i add my custom colors, this order is changed:

```
plot(l29) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00aba4","#73d1cd","#e7e7e7","#bcbddc","#756bb1"))
```

Also the colors are not presented in the order they are specified. ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6S79.png))

How can i control the order of the categories and colors?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the issue, by using the option 'color' within the first line.

Like this:

```
plot(129, colors = c("#00aba4","#73d1cd","#e7e7e7","#bcbddc","#756bb1"))
```

I will have to test if this works throughout my script.